# ModuleNotFoundError No module named deepvoice

Tags: python

I am trying to work on Deepvoice.
But facing an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "e:/STudy/UE/Project/deepvoice-master/deepvoice/models/g2p.py", line 8, in 
> **from deepvoice.data.cmudict import get_cmudict, test_dataset_cmudict**

ModuleNotFoundError: **No module named 'deepvoice'**

I get my code from https://github.com/israelg99/deepvoice/tree/master/deepvoice/models

```
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Activation, TimeDistributed, Bidirectional, LSTM, GRU, Dense, InputLayer, RepeatVector, Input
from keras.optimizers import Nadam
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model

from deepvoice.data.cmudict import get_cmudict, test_dataset_cmudict
from deepvoice.util.util import sparse_labels
```

Comment: your python file must be in the same folder as deepvoice folder

Comment: or it had to be installed via pip